# getting the arguments (list) of a specific (user defined ) PHP function

Tags: php, function, user-defined-functions

is there a way to achieve this in PHP?

```
echo list_args('a_user_defined_function_name_here_such_as_say_hello');
```

and this outputs something like

```
$first_name
$last_name
```

for a function defined as;

```
function say_hello($first_name, $last_name){
     echo "Hello $first_name $last_name";
}
```

So basically, what I'm looking for is a function explainer or something of that sort... & if that thing can get into a php doc based comment extractor. that would be even better..

Comment: Look at [`ReflectionFunction`](http://www.php.net/reflectionfunction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`ReflectionFunction`](http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionfunction.php) class to do this:

```
function list_args($name) {
    $list = "";
    $ref = new ReflectionFunction($name);
    foreach ($ref->getParameters() as $param) {
        $list .= '$' . $param->getName() . "\n"; 
    }
    return $list;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.. that really does it...  I was at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reflection.examples.php page, there I see some more options... But they got their examples based on `shell` calls. How do I make a piece like `$ php --rf strlen` work in a PHP page... 5.3+

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ReflectionFunction`.

```
function list_args($function) {
    $func = new ReflectionFunction($function);
    $res = array();
    foreach ($func->getParameters() as $argument) {
        $res[] = '$' . $argument->name;   
    }
    return $res;
}
```

```
print_r(list_args('say_hello')); // outputs Array ( [0] => $first_name [1] => $last_name )
```